# Radio buttons formtastic bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, rubygems, radio-button, formtastic

I just added the formtastic bootstrap gem to my ruby on rails bootstrap application. This successfully renders all my forms correctly, but strangely, all of my radio buttons have disappeared! I haven't yet been able to find out why that is the case. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Is there a new class for formtastic bootstrap radio buttons?

**EDIT:** I noticed that adding `:inline => true`, partially solves the issue by showing the radio buttons in the same line as the label. Although this at least makes the radio buttons show up, I am looking for a way for them to **show up and be vertically aligned properly**. Unfortunately, adding the following does nothing to help:

```
:input_html => {:style => 'vertical-align: top'},
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have even tried floating the radio buttons and adding padding to my forms in case my radio buttons were present but hidden. That did nothing to make them appear. I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that bootstrap adds padding and margins that make your radio buttons disappear. I eventually ended up overriding these with margin: auto and padding: inherit by adding a custom formtastic_changes.css and importing it in my application.css.scss after importing bootstrap.css.